# Why are my fig leaves yellowing?

Tags: trees, figs

I planted this fig tree a couple of months ago and although at first the leaves looked good, the new ones have been increasingly more yellowed. I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong, I water it once a week, a couple of times if the weather is above 90 during the day.

I realize the photo makes it look like there is grass underneath it, but that's just clippings, I've kept the area around it pretty clear of grass. I am in zone 8B.[image]

Comment: I tested the pH and it looks like it's around 6.5 which, iirc, is in the desirable range. Should I try to fertilize with some kind of iron supplement?

Comment: Nothing suspicious I can think of. The soil around it is pretty heavy clay, but we filled in better soil in a hole around 18 inches diameter and probably 2 feet deep, mixed with some of all this stuff:  https://goo.gl/photos/NxJzBAipgyraejJQ9 I water approximately 5 gallons of water at a time.

Comment: I think you might have over watered it, or at least washed out any goodness in the soil- when you do water it again just give it a plant tonic type feed- should green the thing up nicely. Do it a bit on the weak side, go for a feed with micronutrient mix, possibly an organic source like seaweed, if the feed get splashed or runs away it won't damage anything else. But it will take a few weeks, so don't over do it if nothing happens over night- perhaps once a month at most to start off with.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I read your information closely enough.  You need to give this plant fertilizer.  It is struggling on many accounts.

Those clippings are freshly killed organic material.  Anything alive that dies has to be decomposed.  Starts instantly.  Those decomposing organisms need nitrogen for energy.  Non decomposed organic matter causes nitrogen to be depleted.

If you want figs someday we need to talk about formulations of fertilizer to promote reproductive growth.  Right now this plant needs a balanced fertilizer.  Watering is not a problem at all...just chemistry or 'nutrients' your plant needs desperately to make its own food via photosynthesis.  The chlorophyll in your plant are being put on hold.  Plenty of sunlight, water but no chemicals that that plant needs to do photosynthesis.  Nitrogen, Phosphorus, Potassium and possibly some micronutrients.

Weeds really really get hugely magnified as a problem.  They just are not...a big deal.  Fertilizer is just as important as water and sunlight and drainage.  Try Osmocote 14-14-14  extended release.  Very safe very sane.  Lasts a long long time.